# What impact would Riemann's conjecture if it had to be demonstrated as a whole?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

I ask myself for many years without ever having answers that suit me.

> What impact would Riemann's conjecture if it had to be demonstrated as
>   a whole?  What would be the impact on our lives?

I already know that the Riemann hypothesis holds its importance in number theory, particularly on prime numbers.

The Riemann hypothesis is one of seven Millenium problems, a reputed insurmountable mathematical challenge posed by the Clay Mathematics Institute in $2000$. One of the criteria why the institute has chosen seven problems was that the resolution would be a great interest to advance mathematics and society.

Can you share me your opinion on this question?

P.S. I already know there exists a similar question : [Proving the Riemann Hypothesis and Impact on Cryptography](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272296/proving-the-riemann-hypothesis-and-impact-on-cryptography) and [What is so interesting about the zeroes of the Riemann $\zeta$ function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136417/what-is-so-interesting-about-the-zeroes-of-the-riemann-zeta-function). However, the question is not exactly the same.

**The question has been modified**

Comment: The Riemann Hypothesis has no impact on RSA/criptography/secutiry whatsoever since it although predicts stuff about the distribution of primes, it doesn't say anything about methods of factorization. 

RSA is powerful because factoring numbers that are a product large primes is computationally difficult, and nothing short of an algorithm that finds prime factors of a given number faster will break it.

Comment: RSA is by no means the most important real world cryptographic system.

Comment: Extremely similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272296/proving-the-riemann-hypothesis-and-impact-on-cryptography

Answer (score -1):

Notwithstanding Godel's proof, it would be another instance that if a conjecture
seems true, it will eventually be proven to be so. I put this in the same class
as the Collatz conjecture. Ed Gray